# Почему getline считывает новую строку в следующем вызове?

Tags: строки, c++

То есть допустим в файле много строк и при первом вызове считается первая строка и закончится на \n или разделителе, а потом ещё раз вызовем и getline начинает считывание со следующей строки или со следующего символа после разделителя. Так вот, там какой то счетчик стоит или как это реализовано?

Comment: там указатель на следующий байт который надо прочитать

Comment: А в каком виде тот указатель хранится?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) получает первым параметром указатель на [стрим](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/), у которого есть функция rdbuf, возвращающая указатель на [внутренний буфер - streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/), который хранит данные. Этот streambuf предоставляет интерфейс для чтения - он может прочитать символ, подвинуть указатель. Но фишка в том, что этот класс (точнее его наследники) может оборачивать как файл на диске, так и массив в памяти.  Если посмотреть на его реализацию, то там есть указатель, но он не обязательно будет такой, как Вы себе представляете.

Я посмотрел сорцы, взяв их с линуксового gcc 4.8.1, я немного их поправил (исключительно переименование переменных и раскрытие некоторых функций). Русские комментарии - мои.

```
std::istream&     getline(std::istream& is, std::string& str, char delim)
{
    size_t extracted = 0;
    typename __ios_base::iostate __err = __ios_base::goodbit;
    typename __istream_type::sentry __cerb(is, true);
    if (__cerb)
    {
        __try
        {
          // Avoid reallocation for common case.
            str.erase();
            char buf[128];
            size_t len = 0;
            int c = is.rdbuf()->sgetc(); // взять текущий символ

            // кусок ниже читает посимвольно в буфер, если буфер полон, то сбрасывает его в строку
            while (extracted < str.max_size() && c != eof && c != delim) // пока есть куда писать и не достигли конца файла/строки
            {
                if (len == sizeof(buf) / sizeof(char)) // если буфер полный, то добавим его в строку
                {
                    str.append(buf, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(char));
                    len = 0; // и скажем, что буфер пуст
                }
                buf[len++] = (char)c; // текущий символ в буфер
                ++extracted;
                c = is.rdbuf()->snextc(); // перейти к следующей позиции и прочитать символ.
            }
            str.append(buf, len); // буфер в строку

            // на этот момент в строку вычитали до разделителя
            // если текущий символ - конец файла, то выставим специальный файл
            if (c == eof)
                __err |= __ios_base::eofbit;
            // если текущий символ - разделитель, то вычитаем его
            else if (c == delim)
            {
                ++extracted;          
                is.rdbuf()->sbumpc(); // вычитать текущий символ и продвинуться вперед.
            }
            // если попали сюда и символ не разделитель и конец файла - выставляем флаг ошибки
            else
                __err |= __ios_base::failbit;
        }
        // обработка всяких исключений
        __catch(__cxxabiv1::__forced_unwind&)
        {
            is._M_setstate(__ios_base::badbit);
            __throw_exception_again;
        }
        __catch(...)
        {
          // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
          // 91. Description of operator>> and getline() for string<>
          // might cause endless loop
            is._M_setstate(__ios_base::badbit);
        }
    }
    // если дошли сюда и не смогли извлечь ни одного символа - выставим флаг ошибки
    if (!extracted)
        __err |= __ios_base::failbit;
    if (__err)
        is.setstate(__err);
    return is;
}
```